# Weird behavior of UpdatePanel with Session vs. ViewState

Tags: c#, session, viewstate

Good morning,

This is much more of a WTF is going type question than anything else.

My application is using **ViewState**. I have placed a **UpdatePanel** on my app that is solely for testing purposes. All it does is hits my log table each second and generates a real time log console for me to see how the app is processing things.

This morning i decided to switch my use of **ViewState to Session**. Now my UpdatePanel no longer is running synchronously and "pauses" till the operation is done to update the UpdatePanel/Console.

Switching back to ViewState makes things run normally...

Also, the functions that my UpdatePanel is invoking has no relation to ViewState or SessionState and is not calling on either...

I have been able to reproduce this behavior in  small test sample:

### TestUpdatePanelWithSession.Master

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="TestUpdatePanelWithSession.master.cs" Inherits="Tester2._0.TestUpdatePanelWithSession1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Enabled="True" Interval="1000"></asp:Timer>
        <div>
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1"
            UpdateMode="Always"
            runat="server">
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
            </Triggers>
            <ContentTemplate>

                <%= System.DateTime.Now.ToString("mm:ss") %>

                    </div>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

### TestUpdatePanelWithSession.aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/TestUpdatePanelWithSession.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="TestUpdatePanelWithSession.aspx.cs" Inherits="Tester2._0.TestUpdatePanelWithSession" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <asp:Label ID="lblTest" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    <asp:Button ID="btnStartTest" runat="server" Text="Test" OnClick="btnStartTest_Click" />
</asp:Content>
```

### TestUpdatePanelWithSession.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Tester2._0
{
    public partial class TestUpdatePanelWithSession : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                Session["SomeIndex"] = 50000;
            }
        }

        protected void btnStartTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
                Session["SomeOtherIndex"] = i;

                lblTest.Text = ((int)Session["SomeIndex"] + (int)Session["SomeOtherIndex"]).ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above code works fine if you change all the Session to ViewState. What the heck is going on??

Thanks in advance for the lesson...

Comment: With no code there's nothing we can do.

Comment: I'm really not sure what code to show you here. It's across my entire application. The behavior starts when i switch from using ViewState to using Sessions to store various objects. There surely must be some explanation that explains the behavior of the UpdatePanel when this switch is done (without looking at code)? Or perhaps it should work just fine with Session as it does with ViewState, in which case i'll try identify the area that is causing the UpdatePanel to do this.

Comment: I can ensure you that using Session in an UpdatePanel does not change it's behavior, I've been using it extensively while I was working with ASP .net.

Comment: @Gusman, i have been able to reproduce the behavior in a test sample which i have added above.

Comment: The ContentPlaceholder is outside the UpdatePanel...

Comment: Few lines down on TestUpdatePanelWithSession.Master

Comment: Yes, I modified the question when I saw it was inheriting a master page

Comment: Correct, i'm not looking to place the whole page in a UpdatePanel, only a small console window on the bottom of the masterpage

Comment: Then that's the correct behavior, it was not very clear on the question... anything outside the updatepanel will cause a full POST and the execution will pause until it responded, the Session may introduce a little delay, yes, that's true, but will not lock anything on an updatepanel.

Comment: lblTest.Text = ... obviously doesn't do anything until the loop completes. Just a quick and dirty test sample, lblTest doesn't really even need to be there to prove the behavior.

Comment: Also, in your example you can remove the Session at all, the sleep is creating the delay, so Session will not influence it at all, test it.

Comment: How is it that ViewState is changing this scenario?

Comment: That's a really good question, I mean, it's not normal that because you use a ViewState it does not block when a POST is done. Can you try to change in this example the Session to a ViewState? I think that will not do anything. The only thing I can think is the little overhead introduced because the session restoring, ViewState is faster, so it may be blocking but for less time and then it's not noticeable. Which Session provider you use? In memory? Db? Files? Custom provider?

Comment: I have tested this and as mentioned when you change Session to ViewState, the updatepanel updates every second as expected. Changing to to Session introduces the pause of the timer.

Comment: Asp.Net provider (System.Web.SessionState.HttpSessionSate)

Comment: Ok, I'm a bit rusty with ASP .net and I'm starting to remember things but I'm not totally sure. Try something, don't add a ViewState but remove the Session from your example. Does this still block the call?

Comment: Just tested - no it does not stop the updatepanel. Introducing Session into the mix is what is causing the behavior.

Comment: Ok, gimme a bit of time, I'm going to arm the test project because that makes no sense at all, I will be back after some tests

Comment: Awesome! I'm glad i am not going insane...

Comment: Ok, found what's happening. Let's go to a chat so I can explain it. By the way you are right, is the session what it's locking this, but I know why it never happened to me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142928/discussion-between-gusman-and-nugs).

Answer (score 4):

After testing the example it's clear that the problem comes from the readwrite lock from the session.

Removing the session use from the Page_Load avoids this behavior, but that's a bit strange as the code is not being hit when the updatepanel calls the page. Even moving the code to other function, calling it on another thread or using a task does not prevent this behavior.

It seems that ASP .net is analyzing the code and when there is code using the session, even if it's not executed, it blocks the session what prevents the normal execution of the callbacks. Leaving only session manipulation on control events seems to work fine.

Only solution to this for what I have tested is to remove the Page_Load session manipulation, what in some scenarios can be unavoidable.